# PHP === and ? and : symbol meaning

Tags: php

This is an extract from a WebSocket client, what does the following code line mean/do ?

```
$frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? $payloadLength + 128 : $payloadLength;
```

I read it this way (check below)

```
If Masked == True Then $frameHeadHead[1] = $payloadLength + 128 / $payloadLength
```

I don't understand the `($masked === true)` as well as I dont understand the `: $payLoadLength;` (what is the `:` symbol for ?)

And what if `Masked == False` ? There is no result ?

Comment: Please search properly before you ask a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That(?:) is called the **[ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)**.

```
(condition) ? /* if condition is true then return this value */ 
            : /* if condition is false then return this value */ ;
```

Also **[===](http://au.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)** compares the internal object id of the objects. It is used for strict comparison. `"==="` means that they are identical.

**On a side note:**

> **Note:** Please note that the ternary operator is an expression, and that
>   it doesn't evaluate to a variable, but to the result of an expression.
>   This is important to know if you want to return a variable by
>   reference. The statement return $var == 42 ? $a : $b; in a
>   return-by-reference function will therefore not work and a warning is
>   issued in later PHP versions.

Comment: +1 for actually giving the name when all the other answers don't even mention it.

Comment: About `===` it is strict comparison which checks for data types as well

Answer (score 5):

```
$frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? $payloadLength + 128 : $payloadLength;

it  conditional statement like if and else  

 if($masked === true){ $payloadLength + 128 } else {$payloadLength;}
```

Comment: why down vote reason ??????????????

Comment: poorly formatted, for one.

Comment: Ok thanks.But please prefer on logic because your problem solve then our purpose solve boss.

Answer (score 3):

first: the `===` checks if both the value and the type equal (so while `false==0` is true, `false===0` isn't). the reverse would be `!==`.

the `var=bool ? value1 : value2` statement is the same as:

```
if(bool){
  var=value1;
}else{
  var=value2;
}
```

so your line translates to:

```
if($masked===true){
  $frameHead[1] = $payloadLength + 128;
}else{
  $frameHead[1] = $payloadLength;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
If Masked == True Then $frameHeadHead[1] = $payloadLength + 128 
Else $frameHeadHead[1] = $payloadLength
```

Answer (score 2):

Its [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

```
$frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? $payloadLength + 128 : $payloadLength;
```

Means:

```
If Masked === True 

Then $frameHeadHead[1] = $payloadLength + 128 

Else

Then $frameHeadHead[1] = $payloadLength
```

Answer (score 2):

Check below:

## Why we use === instead of == ?

`==` is used for matching the value.
`===` is used for matching the value with datatype.

More precisely, lets check one example -

```
99 == "99" // true
99 === "99" // false
```

## (?:) mean

This is called a ternary operator. It means

```
$frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? $payloadLength + 128 : $payloadLength;

if ($masked === true) {
    $frameHead[1] = $payloadLength + 128;
} else {
   $frameHead[1] = $payloadLength;
}
```

Comment: Why you guys down voting correct answers???

Comment: Don't encourage questions in which no effort are made.

Comment: @Manwal, yes right :) don't understand the problem of others, why they do so.

Comment: @SankalpSrivastava, then downvote the question, not the answer :).